# How can I have Jitsi on sudomain1.mysite.com and also on subdomain2.mysite.com and each be isolated from one another?

Tags: nginx, multi-tenant, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I have configured Jitsi before to work on a single subdomain, usually meet.mysite.com/customroomname

My setup involves -> nginx on google cloud compute on an Ubuntu server where I have already installed Jitsi before

However; I know find myself needing to expand on the current setup and am looking for the following:

My possible new setup -> nginx -> 2 instances of Jitsi for two different subdomains of mysite.com

1. Each subdomain must have their own customized branding
2. Each subdomain must be isolated -> meaning subdomain1.mysite.com/roomA should be and independent conference from subdomain2.mysite.com/roomA

What I've been able to research:

1. Jitsi has multi-tenant configuration from out of the box in 2023 (or so it says on one of the community issueings) but in the example it mentions using mysite.com/groupA/roomA and mysite.com/groupB/roomA. This is not ideal as my inquiry would be on using the tenants on different subdomains as explained before.
2. I've seen on youtube videos that you can have one Jitsi server and several Videobridge instances connected to it. According to documentation, Jitsi already comes configured to scale like this. I don't understand fully if using more Videobridges would allow me to use the structure I need or if it would just easy the load on the video calls.

I've been at this a couple weeks and haven't really found information on this.

Any comment on what I should do or where I can find more info on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.